# Paper by Mumford

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, laplacian

In the paper of "The spectrum of difference operators and algebraic curves",
by P. van Moerbeke and D. Mumford, Acta Mathematics, vol.143, 1979,
(link: http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/1979a--SpectrumDiffOps-NC.pdf)
the following paper of Mumford is cited:

[26] Mumford, D. The Spectra of Laplace-like periodic partial difference operators and
algebraic surfaces, to appear.

It seems I can't find this paper. Did it appear under a different name?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it did not appear. There is no trace of it on Mumford's carefully edited and commented [homepage](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/diverse.php).

Comment: Is it possible it was "incorporated" in something else?

Comment: Ask him by email: David_Mumford@brown.edu